# Is there anyway to find out if an edge is random in a weighted graph?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I have a weighted graph with density more than 80%. I know that some of the edges are random, but I don't know how to score edges or nodes. Is there any way to calculate it or compare my graph to random graph in some way? Or any threshold to cut edges with weight less than threshold?